# My Ubuntu 20.04 does not detect any external monitors

Tags: 20.04, monitor

I have a Lenovo ThinkPad Pro DisplayLink Plug and Play docking station, with one monitor connected via Display Port and the other one connected via VGA connection.
I have tried purging all Nvidia driver configurations and reinstalling the 470.182.03 version.
I have tried power cycling the docking station, however, in the Display settings, no monitor is detected.

Answer (score -1):

I just fixed it by installing DisplayLink-driver from the synaptic website.
The clue was a sticker on the docking station stating “DisplayLink plug and display”.